# bug resulting from reading file

Tags: python, regex, file-io

I am facing a rather elusive bug which seems to be caused by reading from a file. 
I have simplified my program to demonstrate the issue:

consider this program that works fine:

```
import re

sourceString="Yesterday I had a pizza for lunch it was tasty\n";
sourceString+="today I am thinking about grabbing a burger and tomorrow it\n"; 
sourceString+="will probably be some fish if I am lucky\n\n\n";
sourceString+="see you later!"

jj=["pizza","steak","fish"]

for keyword in jj:
    regexPattern= keyword+".*";
    patternObject=re.compile(regexPattern,re.MULTILINE);
    match=patternObject.search(sourceString);
    if match:
        print("Match found for "+keyword)
        print(match.group()+"\n")
    else:
        print("warning: no match found for :"+ keyword+"\n")
```

I am using a very straightforward regex pattern but I am getting the gist of the regex from my array `jj`

the script works as expected (matches patterns containing "pizza" and "fish" but does not match "steak")

now In my actual program I am trying to read these keywords from a file (I don't want to hardcode in the source)

so far I have this:

```
import re

sourceString="Yesterday I had a pizza for lunch it was tasty\n";
sourceString+="today I am thinking about grabbing a burger and tomorrow it\n"; 
sourceString+="will probably be some fish if I am lucky\n\n\n";
sourceString+="see you later!"

with open('keyWords.txt','r') as f: 
    for keyword in f:
        regexPattern= keyword+".*";
        patternObject=re.compile(regexPattern,re.MULTILINE);
        match=patternObject.search(sourceString);
        if match:
            print("Match found for "+keyword)
            print(match.group())
        else:
            print("warning: no match found for :"+ keyword)
```

where keyWords.txt will contain the following:

```
pizza
steak
fish
```

but this breaks the code because somehow only the LAST keyword in the file will successfully match (if a match exists).

What gives?

Comment: Don't just assume that it is a bug.  That is simply because each line has a new-line character at the end that you didn't account for.

Comment: ..which means due to me not accounting for the newline the program has a bug right? I didn't say the language specification has a flaw

Comment: I'm sorry; I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with open('keyWords.txt','r') as f: 
    for keyword in f:
        regexPattern = keyword.strip() + ".*";
```

Use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to remove any [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) characters from `keyword`. If you know for certain that there won't be any leading whitespace, [`rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) is sufficient.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Great effort